# Angular 4 Javascript Plugins How to use

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, and developing an Angular-Spring project

For my frontend,
I'm using this bootstrap project as base: https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4

It has, inside layout/bs-components/components, several components like date-picker, modal, pagination, etc

But I can't find the logic to import and use this components, I've imported the date-picker.component.ts file of Date-Picker for example, but can't use it, tried the example of the date-picker.component.html file, no use too..

Like I said, I'm really new to Angular, and have no clue how to proceed..can anyone help?

Comment: For datepicker, try https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: And also in general: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: after sometime, I got it..thanks @dhilt